# Unable to see images in Camera roll in iPad Simulator when run at iPhone resolution

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios9

I made an image editing app for `iPhone`, and it got rejected because the app is not able to run on `ipad` at iphone `resolution`. It failed in both `1x` and `2x` `resolution`.

When I click choose `photo`, I present the `camera picker` to select a pic, but `camera picker` is not showing any `images` in the `simulator`.(I didnt test this in real device, I beleive apple will test this in real device) It works normally in `iPhone`, and also in `iPad` if I make the app `Universal`.

But If I make the app compatible for `iPhone`, then it should also run in `iPad` at `iPhone` resolution, which is not happening in my case!!!

Here are the screenshots of `ipad pro simulator`:

[image]
[image]

After I choose the pic, it should display in the imageview, but I get the blank imageview without image.

[image]

I dont have anything fancy in code. It is a routine camera picker:

```
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = YES;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

- I did try to put a `breakpoint` while `picker` is presented and after the image is selected. The `picker` and the selected image is not nil, but when I preview the selected `image` on `xcode`, it shows a blank `image`:

[image]
[image]

- Surprisingly, when I run the app in iphone simulator xcode showed the image:

[image]

**NOTE:**

- When run the app on `iphone simulator` for the first time, `camera picker` asked `permission` to access the photos.But When I run it on `iPad` at `iPhone` `resolution`, `picker` didnt asked for any permission!!!!

Comment: Did you find the cause and/or a solution for this?

Comment: Not yet, I will update it with more details by the end of the day.

Comment: @bartzy- I made the deployment target as iphone instead of universal and still I'm unable to see the pics on gallery, but I am able to see them once I select them. So there is still an issue with this.

Comment: I see the exact same behavior (can see them only after selecting). I guess this is a new bug?

Comment: I'm having this issue. I've just happened on your question and I'd already started my own. I've linked this question to that, Mine's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37032470/ios-9-3-can-not-get-thumbnail-from-photo-library-using-iphone-app-running-on-ipa