# iOS 9.3 can not get thumbnail from photo library using iPhone App running on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiimagepickercontroller

We have had an iPhone App that's configured to run only as an iPhone App.

One aspect of this App has been able to access the photo library without an issue whatsoever. That is until iOS9.3, where the iPad simulator, from iPad4 and up, will not display photo thumbs at all. It simply shows nothing other than a blank square where the thumb ought to be displayed.

Now, the iPhone simulator works totally fine. Images thumbs are read into and by the ALAssetsLibary.

I've learned that the ALAssettsLibrary is no longer supported on iOS9. Certainly the Apple Class Reference for this object has a redline through all of the methods: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/

- **But if thats the case, why is is that it still functions on an iPhone device, that's 5, 5S, 5C, 6, 6S, 6S Plus?
- And why will it not work on an iPad?
- Has anyone got a workaround?**

I can see that this issue comes about if the App is configured an iPhone-only-app that's being run on an iPad?

I found this link on the Apple dev forum site:
 https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43400, where folk are having the same issue as me? People are reporting this as a bug?

I tried downloading this, too, (link below), as perhaps a means of slotting this in to fix my issues:

https://github.com/guillermomuntaner/GMImagePicker

And it behaves in EXACTLY the same way I'm describing is happening in my App.

- Has anyone seen this before?

Editing now as this link to SO is an individual having exactly the same issue and no answers yet?

[Unable to see images in Camera roll in iPad Simulator when run at iPhone resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942311/unable-to-see-images-in-camera-roll-in-ipad-simulator-when-run-at-iphone-resolut)

Comment: Problem happens when a Universal App, or an iPhone-only App, (an iPhone App that's not specifically meant for an iPad) is used with UIKit image picker. An example of what I am experiencing here can be seen with this project here, https://github.com/solomidSF/YRImagePicker, where exactly the same symptoms can be seen. For the life of me, I cannot understand why no-one else can see this. For selfish reasons, and to push on my own issues, I have added a comment (issue) to this individuals work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - for anyone that has read the above, I can tell you now that iOS10 has fixed this silly issue.